# Converting a HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode to a string

Tags: c#, html, string, html-agility-pack

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("In devolopment","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                usercon(link);
            }

        }
```

.

```
public void usercon(string toprint)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "\r\n";
            richTextBox1.Text += toprint;
            //richTextBox1.
        }
```

I need to be able to convert `link` to a string so that in can be used in the function `usercon`

This is my first time using the `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: What does `usercon` expect? A URL, the hyperlink text, or something else?

Comment: A string(I am filling the required characters)

Comment: @Beall619 String that represent what? URL, HTML tag, or what? Please give as an example of correct value for `link`..

Comment: This will be a web crawler "eventually". A correct `link` would be "https://stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the source code found here:
https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/1_4_0/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.cs
See also (new) documentation: http://html-agility-pack.net/outer-html
HtmlNode has an OuterHtml property and its source on [GitHub](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack).

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("In devolopment","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        usercon(link.OuterHtml);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works however im getting more than just links in the output. I dont know much about html however there is syntax in the output.

Comment: Im sure i can make a filter for correct formats. Other than that what you suggested works!